# Angular: show UTC date as local date, using date filter

Tags: angularjs, date

I'm fetching a json from server that has this date:

`"openingDate":"2015-07-15T23:00:00"`

It is brought just like that from the server.
This is an UTC date, so if I wanted to show this date as local (-0400), it should show 2015-07-15 07:00 PM

In my view, I have all these (all attempts):

```
<p>{{ jsonFromServer.openingDate }}</p>
<p>{{ jsonFromServer.openingDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a' }}</p>
<p>{{ jsonFromServer.openingDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a' : 'UTC' }}</p>
<p>{{ jsonFromServer.openingDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a' : '+0400' }}</p>
<p>{{ jsonFromServer.openingDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a' : '-0400' }}</p>
```

Which show this:

> 2015-07-15T23:00:00
>
> 2015-07-15 11:00 PM
>
> 2015-07-16 03:00 AM
>
> 2015-07-16 07:00 AM
>
> 2015-07-15 11:00 PM

And surprisingly, none of those is the one I want!... I need to print this: 2015-07-15 07:00 PM

**...What do I need to use as parameter?!**

Comment: the timezone in your server and local system is different..The server sents time in UTC timezone but the local system takes the date as local timezone set.You need to synchronize both the timezone to same value or set time zone (-0800)

Comment: @Nicolas ok, i'm now sending the Z at the end and it works. It automatically converts to local time zone without even adding the 3rd argument to the `date(date, format, timezone)` filter. Post it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string returned by your server is not in UTC for [Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date): it lacks the `Z` at the end to make it a proper ISO 8601 UTC timestamp. Sending `2015-07-15T23:00:00Z` instead should do the trick.

Comment: Algo works adding "+00:00"  instead of "Z", eg. `2015-07-15T23:00:00+00:00`